# Registration with Unity

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container, auto-registration

I'm accustomed to using Autofac and with autofac with one line of code I can register all the interfaces in the assembly so that they resolve to whatever classes implement that interface.

In Unity it's looking like I need to register every interface manually.  I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to globally register everything, then for lifecycle differences create individual entries.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity 3 now supports auto-registration.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't in Unity 2.

There are however contrib projects that try to add this behavior on top of Unity, such as:

- [Unity Auto Registration](http://autoregistration.codeplex.com/)
- [Unity Contrib project](https://unitycontributions.codeplex.com/)
- [TecX](https://tecx.codeplex.com/)

**UPDATE**

[Unity 3](https://unity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Unity3ReleaseNotes) seems to be just released that contains support for batch-registration.